# How to use the Scan method

Tags: postgresql, go, methods

I have to use the scan method for get en store my id but the program does not want to compile.

The first time I tried:

```golang
    query := "INSERT INTO " + table + "(" + removeLastRune(columns) + ") VALUES (" + removeLastRune(values) + ") RETURNING id".scan(&id)
```

> id".scan undefined (type untyped string has no field or method scan)

Then I apply the documentation but nothing...

```golang
query := db.QueryRow("INSERT INTO " + table + "(" + removeLastRune(columns) + ") VALUES (" + removeLastRune(values) + ") RETURNING id").scan(&id)
```

> scan undefined (type *sql.Row has no field or method scan, but does have Scan)

An idea of ​​the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the error message:

> scan undefined (type *sql.Row has no field or method scan, but does
> have Scan)

`scan` is undefined but `Scan` is not. Replace `.scan` by `.Scan` in your second example